# A book about encroaching ice

Tags: story-identification

I remember starting, and losing, a book in the late 80s, early 90s, that I have been trying to  remember for a while now.

It's not much to go on, I realise, but the main crux of the plot, until I left the book in a phone booth :/, was an ice age (either implied or stated, I can't recall) was starting, and a (I think implied) glacier was moving closer to the main castle or walled city of the novel.

The setting was not specifically High Fantasy, but a medieval style setting.

The interesting thing I always remember about the book was that the antagonist appeared to be the ice itself, slowly, but inexorably, getting closer.

Comment: I was thinking about *The Ice Schooner* by Michael Moorcock or one of the stories by Keith Roberts that used the same world when I saw your title. However, I don't think it's quite the same as what you've described.

Comment: @jfrankcarr No, it doesn't appear to bet it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could it be Clarke's The Forgotten Enemy? It's not medieval, but concerns a man left in an abandoned city during a renewed ice age, who starts hearing loud scraping noises and eventually realises it's the return of the glaciers.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, looks like a good short story, and I'll probably give it a go, but it wasn't what I was looking for, this was a full novel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [*The Anvil of Ice*](http://www.users.zetnet.co.uk/mike.scott.rohan/winter/anvil.htm) by Mike Scott Rohan, the first in his *Winter of the World* trilogy.

Comment: Apart from it appearing to be much more fantasy based than I recall (it was a long time ago) I think you are correct! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot - the book is sci-fi (but the planet is in a medieval period) - but it could possibly be [Helliconia Winter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helliconia#Synopsis_of_Helliconia_Winter) - book 3 in the Helliconia trilogy.

Comment: Looks like an interesting series, but no. Thanks though, I might check it out